# Template Tag values not rendering

Tags: python, django

I am creating a blog as practice for learning how to use django. I have created the **blog list** and created links to the **blog detail** page. On the blog detail, along with the `blog_Content`, `post_date`, `blog_Title` information that should be on the page I am to also attempting to render the `comments` attached to the specific blog created by the **writer/user**

Issue : The comments attached to the specific writer/user are
 not being rendered.

[Here is the repository if you care to take a look](https://github.com/iivri/Creation)

> Here is all the code :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Writer(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    writer_description = models.TextField(max_length = 400, help_text = "Enter your description here.")




    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:writer-detail', args = [str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username




class Blog(models.Model):

    blog_Title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    blog_Content = models.TextField(max_length = 2000, help_text="Create content here.")


    post_date = models.DateField(default = date.today)


    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-post_date']


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:blog-detail', args = [str(self.id)])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_Title



class Comment(models.Model):


    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Create comment here.")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)




    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-post_date']


    def __str__(self):
        length = 75
        if len(self.comment) > length:
            Title_string = self.comment[:length] + '...'

        else:

            Title_string = self.comment

        return Title_string
```

***blog_detail.html***

```
{% extends "core_template.html" %}


{% block head %}
<title>Content Stories</title>
{% endblock %}



{% block content %}



<li class="list-group-item">

 <p class="display-4">{{blog.blog_Title}}</p>
<hr>
  <p class = "text-muted ">Creater: <a href="">{{ blog.writer}}</a></p>
  <hr>
    <p class="h4 text-muted"> <small> Created On: {{ blog.post_date }}</small></p>
</li>

    <li class = "list-group-item" style = "margin-top: 30px; ">

            <p class = "mb-0 display-5" style="white-space:pre-wrap;"><small>{{blog.blog_Content}}</small></p>

    </li>
```

**This is where the comments are to be rendered but are not doing so.**

> ```
>   <p class="display-4">Comments</p>
>
>   {% for comment in blog.comment_set.all %}
>
>   <hr>
>   <p>{{ comment.writer}} - {{comment.comment}}</p>
>
>   {% endfor %}
>
> </div>
> ```

```
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your loop variable is `comments`, but you access `comment` in the loop.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I fixed that problem but it is still not being rendered.

Comment: Your `Comment` model has no `ForeignKey` to `Blog`. Why would a `Blog` instance have a `comment_set`?

Comment: @schwabseggl Do you think the `Comment` model should have a `blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)` attribute to correct the problem? The `comment_set` is created to return the set of all `Comment` records connected to the particular `Blog` instance

Comment: Yup, that looks about right. `comment_set` would be the default `related_name` of such a fk field.